# Octopress new post seen in rake preview but not published after rake deploy

Tags: ruby, open-source, octopress, blog-engine

I used `rake new_post` and added a new post to my octopress blog.

I can see the new blog post on `localhost:4000` using `rake preview`.

However, after using `rake deploy`, my new post wasn't published.

I can see my post in the master branch in my github repo.

Does anyone has any idea what might be causing this? Many thanks in advance.

### Edit:

Also I used the way described in this [post](http://blog.zerosharp.com/clone-your-octopress-to-blog-from-two-places/) to clone my blog to a new machine. Encountered this problem when started blogging using the new machine. Don't know if that has anything to do with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Octopress docs](http://octopress.org/docs/blogging/):

Check that the `published` status of the post isn't set to `false`.

If it is, it won't show up (though `rake preview` will work).

Comment: It wasn't set when I deployed new post. I just tried to set it explicitly to `true`. But still don't see the new post after deploy. I also tried deleting couple of my old post and surprisingly after `gen_deploy`, they were still there...I am very confused. Again everything looks correct in `preview`.

Comment: `git@github.com:Fatman13/fatman13.github.com.git` and I also used a custom domain `http://fatman13.me` for my blog.

Comment: Okay. I just found out why. When I `setup_github_pages` on my new machine. I set the wrong repo. Completely my own fault. Since I store my blog on `fatman13.github.io`, I should have set it to `fatman13.github.io` instead of `fatman13.github.com`. I will accept @andrewdotnich's answer.